# Product of Transposition Confusion

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to work this out and I'm still getting confused

Say i have the product of transpositions

$\tau = (1 6)(3 2)(1 5)(1 4)$

How does 1 map to 6? The way i'm reading it is that 1 maps to 4 and since 4 isn't contained anywhere else in the other cycle's 1 maps to 4 overall.

This is wrong, I need a detailed explanation on how to read products of transpositions.

Comment: Why is this wrong? 1 maps to 4. while 5 maps to 6.

Comment: If this were to map $1$ to $6$ then that would mean that you should read the permutation from left to right. Some authors have this convention.